# how to increase Time of Token in Speak Easy OTP library

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, one-time-password

```
var express = require('express');
var apiRouter = express.Router();
var speakEasy = require('speakeasy');

apiRouter.get('/test',function(){
 secret=speakEasy.generateSecret({
            length: 20
        });     
        var token=speakEasy.totp({
            secret: secret.base32,
            encoding: 'base32', //Increate Time For valid Token //
            step: 60

        });
        var verified=speakEasy.totp.verify({
                secret: secret.base32,  //argument
                encoding: 'base32',
                token: token
            });     
        console.log(verified);  

});
```

when i use step as 30 or with no step option i will return true.
i want to increase time validity of my token how can i do that what is wrong with this code